# Achievements widget doesn't synchronise in new app

Tags: support, bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

If I click in achievements using the new Stack Overflow app and then go to the mobile version I keep seeing the achievements while using the SE app I wouldn't see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you make this more comprehensible?

Comment: Before when I clicked in SE app to see achievements then after my achievements wouldn't show up in mobile (green background, white text), now it shows, so it is now syncing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in version 1.0.1